# Why is my VLookup not working?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Why do I receive the error "Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"? Error occurs here: `Seg = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Code, rng, 2, False)`

```
Sub RateCode()
Dim I As Long
Dim endRow As Long
Dim Rate_Code() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim Seg As String
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Segment")
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws2.Range("A1:B1300")
        With ws
        endRow = Sheet1.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row
        endRow = endRow
        Rate_Code = Sheet1.Range("F3:F" & endRow)
        For I = LBound(Rate_Code) To UBound(Rate_Code)
            Code = Rate_Code(I, 1)

            If Len(Code) = 5 Then
                Code = "'" & Mid(Code, 3, 2)
                Cells(I + 2, 7).Value = Code
            Else
                Code = "'" & Left(Code, 2)
                Cells(I + 2, 7).Value = Code
            End If
            Seg = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Code, rng, 2, False)
            Seg = Cells(I + 2, 8).Value
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @pnuts I have had a look at those answers but I am still struggling.

Comment: @Anthony please check the `code` (lookup value) returning or not in vlookup and  storing the value in `seg` - try to store the lookup value in cell

Comment: What are you using `With` block for? You don't make use of it anywhere...

Comment: I can see a couple of issues with the code. But the one I think you have a problem with is `Rate_Code = Sheet1.Range("F3:F" & endRow)`. You have a qualified object for `Sheet1`. Try using that: i.e. **`Rate_Code = .Range("F3:F" & endRow)`** as its already within a `With` clause. I would do the same where you are getting `endRow`. Then check the `Code` value when you get to `VLookUp` statement

Comment: Change this Seg = Cells(I + 2, 8).Value to  Cells(I + 2, 8).Value = Seg

Answer (score 0):

try this concept may be helpful to u

```
Sub RateCode()
Dim I, y As Long

    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim Rate_Code() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Seg As String
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Segment")
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws2.Range("A1:B1300")
    With ws

            lr = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

         For I = 3 To lr
            Code = Rate_Code(I, 1)
            If Len(Code) = 5 Then
            Code = "'" & Mid(Code, 3, 2)
            Cells(I + 2, 7).Value = Code
            Else
            Code = "'" & Left(Code, 2)
            Cells(I + 2, 7).Value = Code
            End If
            y = 8
            Cells(I, y) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Code, rng, 6, 0)
        Next I
      End With
    End Sub
```